# sybase updating gigaspace cache on insert/update/delete

Tags: java, triggers, sybase, sap-ase, jms-topic

I am new to database and i am working on an application which has a gigaspace based cache and the backend data is a sybase database.

Unfortunately there are a lot of places from where the DB gets updated via stored procs. Hence i would like to have a way via which i can get notifications whenever my DB is updated.

After doing some research i found that sybase does has the ability to send out events to Tibco EMS but unfortunately it requires separate license.

Is there any other reliable way i can get table update notifications without using a messaging system like may be some kind of rest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a message to a UDP port using syb_sendmsg(); this requires some configuration settings but no license. Note that UDP is not as reliable as TCP.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any more licensed options you could make a trigger on the table and put code in the trigger that would send data to JMS.

Or it can call some custom Java class (Java in database) that could do virtually anything.

Another options i to use XP server and call some external program that would populate the cache or JMS queue.